# draytek vigor 2862 how to setup a remote access VPN

Tags: vpn, draytek

We have the simplest network possible, and are trying to setup the simplest VPN possible to allow remote workers access to the LAN and to administer the draytek firewall.

We have a ZTE router supplied by the ISP which has a fixed external ip of x.x.x.x
This routers LAN address is 192.168.10.1, and provides DHCL to LAN hosts from 192.168.10.10 onwards.

The drayteks fixed WAN address is 192.168.10.2 (and its gateway is obviously the ZTE on 192.168.10.1)
The drayteks LAN DHCP range is 192.168.1.x

Everything works in terms of internet access. I can connect to either the ZTE LAN (with an address of 192.168.10.x "infront" of the FW) or the draytek LAN (192.168.1.x i.e. "behind" the FW)

This is the article we have followed to the letter:

https://www.draytek.com/support/knowledge-base/5322

But it cant establish a connection.

We dont know how to debug this, or what configuration is missing.

Apart from setting a fixed IP, we have made no changes to the default state of the vigor.

I am guessing I dont have to do anything with the firewall, as the article does not mention this.

In my local mac VPN settings, I am putting 192.168.10.2 as the "server address", and connecting my latop to the LAN port of the ZTE (So it can see the WAN port of the draytek directly with NAT/port forwarding as a test).  In the "authentication" settings, I put the user password and "shared secret" I setup in the Vigor.

When i try to connect, I get "The L2TP-VPN server did not respond. Try reconnecting. If the problem continues, verify your settings and contact your Administrator"

Has anyone come across a setup guide for VPN including what has to be setup on the client, using whatever protocol is the easiest?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have fixed this but
The Server Address should be the External Fixed Ip address not the Local Address.